# Orphan removal does not work on session.update function

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a `@OneToMany` relationship. The parent entity also have transient fields. I want to keep these transient fields after save or update. Also I want hibernate to orphan remove for child entities. If I use entityManager.merge, hibernate orphan removes the child entities but also does not keep the transient fields. If I use, session.saveOrUpdate, it keeps transient fields but does not orphan remove.

Example Entities;

```
@Table(name = "parent_entity")
@Entity(name = "ParentEntity")
public class ParentEntity extends PersistentEntity {
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inner_entity")
    private InnerEntity innerEntity = new InnerEntity();
    
    @Transient
    private SomePojo transientField;


    public InnerEntity getInnerEntity() {
        return innerEntity;
    }

    public void setInnerEntity(InnerEntity innerEntity) {
        this.innerEntity = innerEntity;
    }
    
}

@Table(name = "parent_entity")
@Entity(name = "ParentEntity")
public class ParentEntity extends PersistentEntity {
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inner_entity")
    private InnerEntity innerEntity = new InnerEntity();

    public InnerEntity getInnerEntity() {
        return innerEntity;
    }

    public void setInnerEntity(InnerEntity innerEntity) {
        this.innerEntity = innerEntity;
    }
    
}

@Table(name = "child_entity")
@Entity(name = "ChildEntity")
public class ChildEntity extends PersistentEntity {
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "inner_entity")
    private InnerEntity innerEntity;
    
    @Column(name = "child_value")
    private String childValue;

    public InnerEntity getInnerEntity() {
        return innerEntity;
    }

    public void setInnerEntity(InnerEntity innerEntity) {
        this.innerEntity = innerEntity;
    }

    public String getChildValue() {
        return childValue;
    }

    public void setChildValue(String childValue) {
        this.childValue = childValue;
    }

    
    
}
```

As I said, I want to operate save and update over parent and I want hibernate to keep transient fields and make orphan removal.

I have tried entityManager.merge and session.saveOrUpdate but none of the does what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: In other proyects i use it and works with the merge's entityManager method. Try put in the field parent in class child the annotation @JoinColumn

Comment: @JLazar0 I have forgotten the write JoinColumn in the question. In my project it already exists. I updated the question thanks

Comment: When you call merge, how do you do it? you store in the variable that you pass as a parameter the result (entity = entityManager.merge (entity)) ?

Comment: I call savedEntity = entityManager.merge(entity); and I need transient fields in savedEntity

Comment: merge returns the entity saved in DB, try to store the result in another variable since the transient fields are not stored and I think it will be at this point where it is lost

Comment: yes of course that it the point transient field has been lost. actually this is just a simple example, I have many transient and non-transient fields. storing them before save is not an applicable solution for me. I have to have them after save with saved information :)

Comment: Well, it has a bad solution. At the end with JPA the entityManager will return the object with the information stored in DB, you can try to save the complete object A, obtain the object B merge method, and with an Orika type mapping framework and reflection (so that it is a unique method), feed the transient fields of A into entity B returned by the merge method.